# can we trigger chrome extension icon from that extension dashboard?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

we are using manifest v3 and during initial setup customers are not getting that they need to click on icon which is unppinned
can we trigger chrome extension icon and open popup with any button which we place here in right side bar ??

[image]

we want when customer click that login button it trigger the chrome extension icon which is unpinned
login button is

```
  <button id="login-btn" class="pd-login-button m-auto block mt-5 mb-7">
        <spam class="pd-login-button-text">Log in</spam>
        </button>
```

we are using chrome manifest v3

manifest is

```
{
   "background": {
    "service_worker": "worker_wrapper.js"
   },
   "action": {
      "css": "css/internal/popup1.css",
      "default_icon": "icons/pd-useable.png",
      "default_popup": "html/popup/popup.html",
      "default_title": "tool over WhatsApp",
      "js": "js/internal/popup/popup.js"
   },
   "default_locale": "en",
   "icons": {
      "16": "icons/pushdaddy-useable.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "tool over WhatsApp",
}
```

Comment: It's not implemented yet. You can add the popup as a DOM element to the web page e.g. an iframe from web_accessible_resources or use chrome.windows.create in the background script to open a new window.

Comment: what is the full path for popup.html so that it can be loaded in iframe ??

Comment: Use chrome.runtime.getURL as shown in examples for web_accessible_resources.